# PDO::commit() success or failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

The PHP [PDO::commit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) documentation states that the method returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. Does this refer to the success or failure of the statement executions between beginTransaction() and commit()?

For example, from the documentation:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO fruit (name, colour, calories) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    $sth->execute([
        $fruit->name,
        $fruit->colour,
        $fruit->calories,
    ]);
}

$dbh->commit();
```

If any of the above executions fail, will the commit() method return false due to the "all-or-nothing basis" of atomic transactions?

Comment: I don't really recall needing to commit within code-base, have you tried to do it without it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The point of manual transactions is to ensure that multiple statements are either all successful, or none are.

Comment: I think you're over-thinking it. If one fails in this scenario then most likely all will fail and vice-versa. Just add proper error handling to the code and if you're really concerned about what's failing then simply log it. I've never had to use commit in server-side code, I find it unlikely that you have to.

Comment: This is the scenario from the documentation. An example where I will use manual transactions is deleting from one table, and then another. If either delete fails, the other should fail too. So if the first one succeeds and the second fails, the first should then be rolled back, else the data in the database will be in an "in-between" state. This is why I need manual transactions.

Comment: Fair enough. Another workaround would be to execute each $fruit and if it fails then remove the previously inserted ones but I understand that it's not "natural".

Comment: Yeah I guess that would be a way of performing a sort of manual roll back on a database engine that doesn't support transactions like MyISAM. I am using InnoDB though which does support them, so want to take advantage of them.

Comment: @Jonast92 "I've never had to use commit in server-side code", maybe because you never had to make a large scaled application ? Commits are the right choices when you need to prevent database transactions from messing with the internal data. In a series of statements, if one fails, will you just remove the previously inserted ones ? NO, because triggers may have inserted some data between the queries ("in-between"), and it's too complex and pointless to make our own rollback method. When databases just give us the right tool for that. So, no it's not unlikely that the OP needed that.

Comment: When I made that comment I had not, I'd definitely not make this specific comment today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value is based on pdo::commit itself, not the transaction you're trying to commit.
It returns FALSE when there's no transaction active, but it's not very clear whenever it should return TRUE or FALSE.

The executed queries within the transaction itself will success or fail on it's own.
Using the Mr.Tk's example, the transaction will be committed if possible and no error occured while executing the queries in the "try" block and rolled back if an error did occur within the "try" block.

When only evaluating the executed queries within the "try" block, personally I would try to catch a PDOException instead of a normal Exception.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
try {
    // insert/update query
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $dbh->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: According to the [PDO::commit documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php), PHP will throw a `PDOException` when trying to call `commit` when there is no active transaction, not return `false`!

Answer (score 7):

The key part is **to set PDO in exception mode,** while having try-catch only to do a rollback is unnecessary. Thus, your code is all right, no need to change it if all you want is rollback on failure, as long as you have this line somewhere:

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

In case of failure the script will be terminated, connection closed and mysql will be happy to roll back the transaction for you.

In case you still want to rollback manually, you should be doing it properly, not like it is said in the other answers. Make sure that

- you are catching `Exception`, not `PDOException`, as it doesn't matter what particular exception aborted the execution
- you are **re-throwing** an exception after rollback, to be notified of the problem
- also that a table engine supports transactions (i.e. for Mysql it should be InnoDB, not MyISAM).

This checklist is taken from [my article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions) which you may find useful in this or many other aspects as well.

Comment: Are you really sure about this? If i perform 10 different inserts or updates, and in the last one pdo raises an exception, all the 9 other sentences are rolledback?

Comment: I agree with @CarlosGoce: it won't rollback without explicit `begin/rollback` handling. But exceptions will help running a `rollback` as stated by @Mr.TK. In fact you don't even answer the question about `commit`: transactions are useful if you want to cancel a lot of queries previously sent if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Yvan surely it will rollback as a transaction will always be rolled back at a *connection close*. But I would rather agree that with transactions try catch is useful, if used properly.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: thanks for editing your answer, makes it clearer. Although I disagree on the «let the rollback work on its own», because it's easier to see a rollback at some point and know the transaction ends here (else it has no end... but the script's one), I agree on the fact that throwing multiple exceptions is the right way to handled all this, and that the `setAttribute` is needed. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done it like that:

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

try {
     // insert/update query

     $dbh->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
     $dbh->rollBack();
}
```

And always worked as charm! :)

So I think that in Your case if insert would fail application should throw an exception and commit wouldn't even trigger.