# How to get Row Number when insert records from File to DB with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, Transaction and Commit?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, load-data-infile

How to get Row Number when insert records from File to DB with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, Transaction and Commit?

However, only getting `true` or `false`(in fail) with the `var` dump present

Statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`)
```

Script:

```
public function PDO_UL_IUPD($dbUsing, $stmtpre) {
        $started = microtime(true);
        $DB      = [];
        $val     = [];
        $conn    = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_PRE . "" . $dbUsing . "",
            DB_USERNAME,
            DB_PASS,
            array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE       => TRUE,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND       => "SET NAMES UTF8",
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES         => FALSE,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            ));
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try {
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            $count  = 0;
            $RowReg = 0;
            // our SQL statements
            foreach ($stmtpre as $stmt) {
                $count++;
                $conn->exec($stmt);
            }
            $RowReg = $conn->commit();
            echo var_dump($RowReg);
            $DB['SMG'] = "Correct Execution, a csv file has been dumped.<br><br>";
            $DB['R']   = true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $DB['SMG'] = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            $DB['R']   = false;
        }
        return $DB;
    }
```

**Update1 Script:**

Trying to get Row Number from `EXEC` return 0

Script:

```
public function PDO_UL_IUPD($dbUsing, $stmtpre) {
        $started = microtime(true);
        $DB      = [];
        $val     = [];
        $conn    = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_PRE . "" . $dbUsing . "",
            DB_USERNAME,
            DB_PASS,
            array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE       => TRUE,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND       => "SET NAMES UTF8",
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES         => FALSE,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE                  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            ));
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            $count  = 0;
            $RowReg=0;
            $cReg=0;
            // our SQL statements
            foreach ($stmtpre as $stmt) {
                //echo $stmt."<br><br><br>";
                $count++;
                $cReg=$conn->exec($stmt);
                $RowReg=$RowReg+$cReg;
            }
            $conn->commit();
            echo var_dump($RowReg);
            $DB['SMG'] = "Correct Execution, a csv file has been dumped.<br><br><br>";
            $DB['R']   = true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $DB['SMG'] = "Error en Tiempo de Ejecucion: " . $e->getMessage();
            $DB['R']   = false;
        }
        return $DB;
    }
```

**Update 2 statement:**

adding this Return 1

```
SET @row=0;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`)
SET file_line_no = @row:=@row+1;
```

Comment: `exec` returns the row count, not `commit`. Try `$RowReg=$conn->exec($stmt);`

Comment: ok, but it returns 0 when I try to use Excel. when the loaded file has 250k records

Comment: You can check if there's an error with `$conn->errorInfo`. Might be some syntax error

Comment: not normal error becouse it load the data into the DB. i have update the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO::commit() success or failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851360/pdocommit-success-or-failure)

Comment: hey you are out o object: the script work fine but the probllem is around the way to get the number of row inserted from file return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

This script is full suported:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`)
```

But i merge it with other in some Query Like that:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2';
ALTER TABLE tbalename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`);
```

this is wrong, becouse `$PDO->exec()` Cant return the number of affected table or rows.

Instead of it, to solve i need past an array, becouse my script support it like that:

```
$stmtpre[1] = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2';";
$stmtpre[2] = "ALTER TABLE tbalename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";
$stmtpre[3] = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`);";
```