# Get number of affected rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo, load-data-infile

trying to get the affected row return 0 file contain 250k records:

```
$affectedRows = 0;
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec(
        "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE Col3 BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-31 00:00:00';
        ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`)");

echo var_dump($affectedRows);
```

Store the CSV but Return 0

Comment: Where is `$affectedRows` from. What is `vardump`?

Comment: PDO doesn't allow you to execute multiple queries with a single `$pdo->exec()` call.

Comment: You're also missing quotes around the argument to `exec()`.

Comment: @JNevill you see this line `echo vardump($affectedRows);` ??? And Vardump is the metod to outpud the return data.

Comment: I though it was var_dump() but I don't write much pho anymore so perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: I also don't see where the $affectedrows variable is set. Or,again, maybe my php/pdo is rusty and that magically gets filled?

Comment: i have update the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

This script is full suported:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`)
```

But i merge it with other in some Query Like that:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2';
ALTER TABLE tbalename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`);
```

this is wrong, becouse `$PDO->exec()` Cant return the number of affected table or rows.

Instead of it, to solve i need past an array, becouse my script support it like that:

```
$stmtpre[1] = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2';";
$stmtpre[2] = "ALTER TABLE tbalename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";
$stmtpre[3] = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' ( `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`);";
```

Same this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370701/9632001